# Как заповторить условие if?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, admob

После n- количества остановки анимации выполняется показ рекламы, но срабатывает только один раз. Как реализовать повтор показа рекламы каждые n раз.

```
public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
    if (++counter == 3) {
        mInterstitialAd.show();
        counter = 0;
    }
}
```

Код самой рекламы:

```
private InterstitialAd mInterstitialAd;
    private static int counter=0;
mInterstitialAd = new InterstitialAd(this);
        mInterstitialAd.setAdUnitId("ca-app-pub-9225307158641311/329999999999");
        mInterstitialAd.loadAd(new AdRequest.Builder().build());
```

Comment: Попробуйте заменить == на >=

Comment: Ищите ошибку в коде отображения рекламы.

Comment: @eugeneek, Счетчик сбрасывается, оно и так должно работать.

Comment: Добавил код рекламы в вопрос, не знаю даже, что тут неправильно

Comment: Посмотрите с помощью отладчика в какой момент нарушается требуемая логика.

Comment: LogCat после показа рекламы: 11-02 16:52:12.810 3889-3894/? E/ANDR-PERF-MPCTL: Invalid profile no. 0, total profiles 0 only                                        
11-02 16:52:29.549 2637-2648/? E/OperatorSimInfo: Create Res Apk Failed                                                                                                                     11-02 16:52:45.760 1473-2342/? E/IzatSvc_PassiveLocListener: E/Exiting with error virtual void izat_manager::IzatPassiveLocationListener::onLocationChanged(const izat_manager::IzatLoc

Comment: E/WifiHAL: getLowiCallbackTable: requested lowi capabilities: 0x00000004 is not  in supported capabilities: 0x00000003. Return NULL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Дело оказалось в том, что реклама после 1 показа уничтожалась, удалось исправить так:

```
@Override
            public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {
                if (++counter == 10) {
                    counter = 0;
                    mInterstitialAd.show();
                }




            }

@Override

            public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
              // Повтор рекламы после запуска
                mInterstitialAd.loadAd(new AdRequest.Builder().build());
                mInterstitialAd.isLoaded();
    }
```